# Google earth elevation error for specifik coordinates in python

Tags: python, api, google-earth

I am using the Google Earth Engine via Google Colab in python to get the elevation of different coordinates based on latitude and longitude, however not all coordinates return an elevation. Code in Colab:

```
    import ee

    ee.Authenticate()
    ee.Initialize()

    dem = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003')

    xy = ee.Geometry.Point([12, 55])

    elev = dem.sample(xy, 30).first().get('elevation').getInfo()

    print(elev)
```

Some coordinates work fine such as [12, 55], which prints `65` while others such as [50,-4] or [3,3] throws the error shown beneath:

```
        EEException: Element.get: Parameter 'object' is required.
```

How can I avoid the error and get the elevation of this and other points?

Comment: Is it only negative values that cause an error?

Comment: No, positive values can cause the error as well